# Why this error? Connect to sts.amazonaws.com:443 [sts.amazonaws.com/54.239.29.25] failed: connect timed out: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

When assuming IAM role using STS client in Java based lambda, did anyone face and solved this error -
`Connect to sts.amazonaws.com:443 [sts.amazonaws.com/54.239.29.25] failed: connect timed out: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException`

I wonder -
When I have `aws-java-sdk-stsclient` dependency in my pom and hence in my shaded jar, why would there be in internet call? Since lambda is in VPC with SG’s configured, internet access is blocked.

Note - I have to assume role in order to access files on S3 from another AWS account. Updating IAM trust policy to have list access is not an option.

Here is dependency I have in my pom -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.163</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image: View from my external dependencies showing aws-java-sdk-sts libraries]

And Here is my java class where I am assuming role using sts client -

```
public class AWSTokenManager {
        public void awsTokenManager() {
            System.out.println("Inside awsTokenManager method");
            STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("role-arn-here", "us-east-1b")
                    .withStsClient(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build())
                    .withRoleSessionDurationSeconds(900)
                    .build();
            System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
            System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());
            System.out.println("SessionCredentials awsaccesskeyid is - " + stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.getCredentials().getSessionToken());
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *why would there be in internet call?*

Why would there **not** be?  You're accessing the STS service, using the STS client.

Unless you created and configured a [VPC Endpoint for STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_sts_vpce.html) (which you did not mention), the STS endpoint needs to be accessed via the Internet in order to send the request to call `AssumeRole`.